# 3D picking doesnt work on another computer - lwjgl

Tags: java, lwjgl

When I try to put my project and run it on my laptop, everything works fine but 3D picking is messed up. It picks different objects when I click a 3D object.

I have tried in another laptop and it gives the same result. Then I tried fixing my desktop computer's monitor to my laptop to see weather its a resolution problem. But still it gives the same result. But it totally works fine in my desktop computer.

I have a Nvidia 760gtx gpu on my desktop and laptop only has the Intel HD 4500 gpu. Is it because of the gpu?   me. I'm lost. I tried everything.
This is my code to pick 3D objects.

```
public void select(int xx, int yy )
{
        // The selection buffer
        IntBuffer selBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1280).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer();
        int buffer[] = new int[256];

        IntBuffer vpBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(64).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer();
        // The size of the viewport. [0] Is <x>, [1] Is <y>, [2] Is <width>, [3] Is <height>
            int[] viewport = new int[4];

        // The number of "hits" (objects within the pick area).
        int hits;
        // Get the viewport info
            GL11.glGetInteger(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, vpBuffer);
            vpBuffer.get(viewport);


        // Set the buffer that OpenGL uses for selection to our buffer
        GL11.glSelectBuffer(selBuffer);

        // Change to selection mode
        GL11.glRenderMode(GL11.GL_SELECT);

        // Initialize the name stack (used for identifying which object was selected)
        GL11.glInitNames();
        GL11.glPushName(0);

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glPushMatrix();
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();

        /*  create 5x5 pixel picking region near cursor location */
        GLU.gluPickMatrix( (float) xx, (float) yy, 0.001f, 0.001f,IntBuffer.wrap(viewport));

        GLU.gluPerspective(fov, screenResolutionx/screenResolutiony, near, far);
        render();
        GL11.glPopMatrix();
        // Exit selection mode and return to render mode, returns number selected
        hits = GL11.glRenderMode(GL11.GL_RENDER);
        System.out.println("hits: " + hits);

        selBuffer.get(buffer);
            // Objects Were Drawn Where The Mouse Was

            if (hits > 0) {
                  // If There Were More Than 0 Hits
                  choose = buffer[3]; // Make Our Selection The First Object
                  int depth = buffer[1]; // Store How Far Away It Is
                  for (int i = 1; i < hits; i++) {
                        // Loop Through All The Detected Hits
                        // If This Object Is Closer To Us Than The One We Have Selected
                        if (buffer[i * 4 + 1] <  depth) {
                              choose = buffer[i * 4 + 3]; // Select The Closer Object
                              depth = buffer[i * 4 + 1]; // Store How Far Away It Is
                        }
                  }
                  System.out.println("Chosen: " + choose);
            }




}
```

Comment: Please anyone know about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured it out. It is because of the GPU. I tried this method in a nvidia GPU (840m) laptop and it did work fine. But when i switch the gpu to Intel HD 5500 ,selection is not working properly. So my conclusion is using `GL11.glRenderMode(GL11.GL_SELECT)` method for 3D object picking works only with a nvidia GPU. It might work on a ATI GPU (not tested) also but not on Intel.